# найти значение функции z =( ( a - 3 ) * b / 2 ) + c

Tags: java

не ругайте строго, я только учусь...
подскажите правильно ли я понял условие задания??
с этой вашей геометрией вообще никогда не дружил....

```
public class Main {
    //(линейная программа)найти значение функции z =( ( a - 3 ) * b / 2 ) + c

    static int func(int a, int b, int c) {
    int z = ( ( a - 3 ) * b / 2 ) + c;
        System.out.println(z);
    return z;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

func(11,22,33);

    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю причем тут геометрия, но если вам нужна именно `z =( ( a - 3 ) * b / 2 ) + c` формула, то да вы правильно её списали (зачем создавать вопрос не понятно). Я бы над типом параметров подумал, должны ли они быть целочисленными?

Comment: для пущего порядка в `main` лучше сделать `System.out.println(func(11,22,33))` потому что если функция возвращает значение можно его обрабатывать разными способами уже снаружи, выводить, сохранять и т.п. и скобочки `{ }` лучше поровнять чтобы код читался легче.

Comment: благодарю за ответ.